# Can't install aubio library for python

Tags: python, aubio

I've had this problem for hours, and still can't fix it.  I've tried almost everything.
I've tried using both python 3.10 and 3.8 and here is the error I usually get:

```
Collecting aubio
  Downloading aubio-0.4.9.tar.gz (479 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 479.0/479.0 KB 652.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from aubio) (1.21.4)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for aubio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-contrib-python (c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: aubio
  Running setup.py install for aubio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for aubio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cmd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\midiconv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\slicing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\aubio
      running build_ext
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      checking for aubio = 0.4.9
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags aubio = 0.4.9" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: aubio 0.4.9 was not found by pkg-config
      Info: looking for *optional* additional packages
      checking for libavcodec
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavcodec" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavformat
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavutil
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libswresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libswresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for sndfile
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for samplerate
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags samplerate" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: libaubio was not installed or built locally with waf, adding src/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> aubio
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: pkg-config is a linux tool. I am not sure that work on windows at all. The documentation say "aubio is currently a source only package, so you will need a compiler to install it from PyPI. See also Installing aubio with conda for pre-compiled binaries." https://aubio.org/manual/latest/python_module.html#python-install

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a unix based system try installing the `aubio` / `python-aubio` package from your system package manager or app store.

Arch:
`sudo pamac -Syu aubio`

Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install aubio`

Note: this will install aubio globally. Since you can't install `aubio` directly with pip, I suggest as a workaround creating a virtualenv cloning your system packages. Just run:
`python -m venv venv_name --system-site-packages`